# My accumulator is registering as a string....SO LOST

Tags: python, accumulator

My problem is probably simple as usual guys and gals, I've been working on this thing for 13 hours now and I can't get this this to accumulate the names variable.

I need it to count players that I have input data for. This is the error message I'm getting:

```
line 25, in main
    name += 1
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

For this input/output:

```
You will be asked to enter players names and scores
When you have no more names, enter End

Enter Player's Name or end to end program:vxzcvzvc
Enter vxzcvzvc's golf score: 3
Enter Player's Name or end to end program:zcvxcxzvxzv5
Enter zcvxcxzvxzv5's golf score: 6
Enter Player's Name or end to end program:zcvxvczx
Enter zcvxvczx's golf score: 5
Enter Player's Name or end to end program:end
You have written end players records to golf.txt
```

This is my code:

```
def main():
     #Program that reads each player's name and golf score as input
     #Save to golf.txt
     outfile = open('golf.txt', 'w')

     #define name 
     name = 0
     name += 1

     # introduction to user explaining required information to be entered
     print("You will be asked to enter players names and scores")
     print("When you have no more names, enter End")
     print("\n")

     #Enter input, leave blank to quit program
     while True:
         name = input("Enter Player's Name or end to end program:")
         if name == "end":
              break
         score = input("Enter "+ str(name)+"'s golf score: ")

         #write to file golf.txt
         outfile.write(name + "\n")

         outfile.write(str(score) + "\n")

     #output for number of names recorded
     print("You have written", name,"players records to golf.txt")
     outfile.close()
main()
```

Comment: You are using `name` variable as a `string` and as `int` - decide what you want it to be - can't be 2 things simultaneously. That is why you get `TypeError`, cause at first you say `name` is an integer, and then you assign to it `string`-input

Comment: The code as given gives no error.  Rule #1 for posting is an [MVCE](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help.mvce).  Post a minimal, verifiable, and complete example.

Comment: I had it working properly in a previous version of this when my <while> was "anotherPlayer" but it was giving me issues so I trashed the script and started over

Comment: Using better names would help your confusion.  `name_count` would be a better name if you were counting names.  In this case, you assign name to 0 add 1, and then reuse it as a string to hold the player name. There is no error since this version on the code never tries to increment name again.

Comment: mark you are right, I tinkered with this thing many times........

the name += 1 was on line 27 

when I edited it back to line 8 that is where I get the players name in my "acculator line" at the end for the script

Comment: If I use "nameCount" as an accumulator in my "while true loop" where do I put it as a trigger?

Comment: Also, for future posts how did you change my output into a "code style"?

Comment: Code style is triggered when lines are prefixed with 4 spaces. There is a short cut key for that : select multi-line text, Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a separate variable for counting the number of scores that have been written:

```
def main():
    outfile = open('golf.txt', 'w')

    # Change this: 
    count = 0

    print("You will be asked to enter players names and scores")
    print("When you have no more names, enter End")
    print("\n")

    while True:
        name = input("Enter Player's Name or end to end program:")
        if name == "end":
            break
        score = input("Enter {}'s golf score: ".format(name))
        outfile.write(name + "\n")
        outfile.write(str(score) + "\n")
        # add this:
        count += 1

    # change this:
    print("You have written {} players records to golf.txt".format(count))
    outfile.close()

main()
```

Comment: thank you, man it makes me feel so STUPID when all this time was wasted on such a small thing.